# doctrine2 and Symfony2 upload file (mimeTypes for csv), get the right extension

Tags: php, symfony, csv, file-upload, doctrine-orm

I am using the symfony upload method in order to import csv or Excel files into my application.

My problem is that symfony/doctrine don't recognize my csv file if I don't write this mimeTypes `"text/plain"`.

Let me explain correctly. This is my entity code:

```
namespace ...

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Documents
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="documents")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MySpace\MyBundle\Repository\DocumentsRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Documents
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="doc_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $nomDocSuivis;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="doc_path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;
    /**
     * @var string $file
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "100000000", mimeTypes= {"text/csv", "application/csv", "text/excel", "application/excel"}, mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid CSV | Excel file")
     */
    private $file;

    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

Of course, I am using a simple controller method to persist and flush an entity, nothing's wrong here. But when I upload my csv files or Excel files, I have the `mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid CSV | Excel file"`. That is to say, symfony does not recognize my csv files.

Here's my controller code:

```
public function uploadAction()
    {
      $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $doc = new Documents;

      $form=$this->createForm(new DocumentsType(), $doc);
      $form->remove('path');

      if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            // An easy way to handle the file upload is to move it just before the entity is persisted and then set the path property accordingly
            // $docSuivi->upload();
            $doc = $form->get('file');
            $doc = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($doc);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('indexDocuments'));
        }
    }

     return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:Documents:uploadDocuments.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
    }
```

And finally, my Symfony Form Builder:

```
class DocumentsSuivisConsoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('docName')
            ->add('path')
            ->add('file')
            ->add('compteurs')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Documents'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mySpace_myBundle_documents';
    }
```

But I if I add mimeTypes = "text/plain" like this:

```
    /**
     * @var string $file
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "100000000", mimeTypes= {"text/plain", "text/csv", "application/csv", "text/excel", "application/excel"}, mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid CSV | Excel file")
     */
    private $file;
```

It works well, but register the extension as `.txt` instead of `.csv`. **And of course, my `.csv` file becomes a `.txt` file, that I do not want.**

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you uploading the file as a binary to the database or just storing metadata there? Could you please post your controller and form as well? (Not sure if the controller is relevant but might be)

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, upload a file and see which mime type your browser is sending.  If it is uploading the file as text/plain then there is not much you can do about it except to go into your documents class, check for text/plain and change the extension.

Comment: @tftd look at my update, I add the symfony controller and build form for the upload method

Comment: I have a suspicion @Cerad might be right. If your `csv` file was created with notepad/or similar it might have been saved with a mime-type = `text/plain`. Did you try with an actual file created in Excel?